# Как подключить библиотеку с GitHub в андроид проект?

Tags: android, android-library

Хочу подключить [данную библиотеку](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib) в свой андроид-проект. Помогите мне, пожалуйста, с объяснениями, как это сделать! И если можно подробнее. Буду весьма благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто перенесите в свой проект папку `src`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вроде как помогло мне! :)